# WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 error creating a proxy service with only https transport

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I try to create a proxy service with only https transport, I get the following error:
WARNING: EPRs are NULL. Transport configuration may be incorrect

If I add back in the http transport, the error disappears.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this related to https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1624?

Comment: What is the version you are trying. I was able to add following for .5.0 without an issue. <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test1" transports="https" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="https://localhost:9443"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>

Comment: 4.5.1.  I'll try that later today.